# vncserver supports unix domain sockets

Tags: vnc, vnc-server

can you help me in finding a vncserver that supports UNIX domain socket or any other tweak

tightvnc creates a socket file under /tmp/.X11-unix/X${display_number} but i'm not sure that this would work

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with Tigervnc or X2go:

---

## Tigervnc

Tigervnc added Unix domain socket with [`-rfbunixpath`](https://tigervnc.org/doc/Xvnc.html).

You can obtain Tigervnc in two ways at less, using the official build or your OS packages system, and they differ a little bit (for Debian at less, maybe other  OS's too):

- #### official build (preferred):

you can build it from source or use the binaries from [here](https://bintray.com/tigervnc) like that:

```
curl -sSfL -o tigervnc-1.10.0.x86_64.tar.gz https://bintray.com/tigervnc/stable/download_file?file_path=tigervnc-1.10.0.x86_64.tar.gz
tar xz -f tigervnc-1.10.0.x86_64.tar.gz
```

then copy it to `/usr/local` or where ever you like.

create a password to protect the vnc server with: `vncpasswd`

run the server:

```
vncserver :1 -geometry 1600x1000 -rfbunixpath /tmp/vnc_myunixSocket -nolisten tcp
```

you can now for example connect with ssh remotely with:

```
ssh -fx -e none -o ExitOnForwardFailure=yes -L 4321:/tmp/vnc_myunixSocket user@IP & 
vncviewer localhost:4321
```

- #### using the package manager (Debian apt)

Tigervnc of Debian (buster) is different than the official build and have a problem in their vncserver (a perl script), you cannot use the Unix socket because they check for an open port and if not found then the script consider that vncserver got a problem and close it. to solve this you  can remove the check from that script or use xtigervnc directly without using the vncserver script like that:

```
Xtigervnc :1 -auth ~/.Xauthority -geometry 1600x1000 -depth 24 -rfbwait 30000 -rfbauth ~/.vnc/passwd -pn -localhost -SecurityTypes VncAuth -nolisten tcp -rfbunixpath /tmp/vnc_myunixSocket
```

as you see it is not nice but it works, that is why I prefer the official build.

---

## x2go

x2go uses Unix domain socket too, and do not need any open port in the server.
I always used the official [site](https://wiki.x2go.org/doku.php/doc:installation:x2goserver) to install it, but now I see it was added to Debian repository too. it works fine too, this is better for low resource servers because it use an X server in your client PC (VNC uses the X of the server so consumes more resources)