# Is there a VNC server that listens on a Unix domain socket instead of a standard port (5900)?

Tags: linux, vnc

I am trying to use a vncserver (There are many variants. I am ok with anything.) which listens on a Unix domain socket instead of the standard port (5900) (i.e., an Internet domain socket). I have not found any version supporting it. (I do know what domain sockets are and want to use server and client on the same box. Weird requirement.) I have got the client for it. I kind of modified one to support my requirement. Does any one know any vnc server which supports this requirement?

Comment: Why do you need/want to run VNC client and server on single box?

Comment: This question probably belongs to [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/faq) or [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/faq).

Comment: @Sampo: Some weird thing I need to get working.

Comment: you can use tigervnc or x2go for that, here I added how https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11314866/vncserver-supports-unix-domain-sockets

Answer (score -1):

I suspect https://stackoverflow.com/a/2150188/20146 would work.

Here are some extra characters to mollify StackOverflow, which insists on at least 30 :-|